# Windows-build-tools installation

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, npm

Windows 10, Node - v12.17.0, NPM - 6.14.4, Node-gyp - v7.1.0

I try to install windows-build-tools : $npm install -g windows-build-tools

Here is the error:

```
$npm install -g windows-build-tools
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./dist/index.js

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall: `node ./dist/index.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Here is my system env PATH:

```
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

Here is my system env CompSpec:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts
```

Comment: Are you running the script from an elevated/admin Powershell?

Comment: @DanStarns im running it on gitbash

Comment: hmmm do u think that im having a problem on my enviroment variables?

Comment: it says [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools) 2nd line to run with PowerShell as Administrator. try that

Comment: An error occured while running it with PowerShell as Admin

```PS C:\Windows\system32> npm --version
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed```

Comment: check your npm path `npm bin -g`

Comment: @ThakurAmit  ```npm bin -g``` C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me is that i just update my npm to latest and boom problem solved `npm install -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 0):

[@unamen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13530722/unamen) try editing the env path variable

your current env var

```
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

updated env var

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

Comment: Will try this one.

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve the problem pls help

Comment: I would suggest you to first install python 2.7, restart , and then install WBT

Comment: Do i really need to install python2.7?

Comment: you can keep both 2.7 as well as 3, it won't bother you, it worked for me

Comment: okay ill try this one. I hope this one will fix this  ^_^

Comment: no it didnt work T_T. what else should i do after i install the 2.7?